# Unable to run Examples given by Ballerina Integrator Tutorials

Tags: integration, wso2-enterprise-integrator, ballerina, integrator, wso2-bi

I am new to Ballerina and Ballerina Integrator While running the sample given by Ballerina Integrator tutorials getting an Error. Please help me to sort out the issues.

For the reference here i shared the screenshot and log file
[image: Error Screenshot].

````
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.ballerinalang.jvm.types.BRecordType.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/ballerinalang/jvm/types/BPackage;IZI)V
    at ballerina.lang_annotations.___init.$createTypeInstances(lang.annotations)
    at ballerina.lang_annotations.___init.$createTypes(lang.annotations)
    at ballerina.lang_annotations.___init.$currentModuleInit(lang.annotations)
    at ballerina.lang_annotations.___init.ballerina_lang_annotations__init_(lang.annotations:65535)
    at 13473.upload_to_ftp.___init.$moduleInit(upload_to_ftp:65535)
    at 13473.upload_to_ftp.___init.$lambda$$moduleInit$(upload_to_ftp)
    at org.ballerinalang.jvm.scheduling.SchedulerItem.execute(Scheduler.java:486)
    at org.ballerinalang.jvm.scheduling.Scheduler.run(Scheduler.java:237)
    at org.ballerinalang.jvm.scheduling.Scheduler.runSafely(Scheduler.java:207)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

[2019-11-21 12:17:32,502] SEVERE {b7a.log.crash} - org.ballerinalang.jvm.types.BRecordType.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/ballerinalang/jvm/types/BPackage;IZI)V 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.ballerinalang.jvm.types.BRecordType.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/ballerinalang/jvm/types/BPackage;IZI)V
    at ballerina.lang_annotations.___init.$createTypeInstances(lang.annotations)
    at ballerina.lang_annotations.___init.$createTypes(lang.annotations)
    at ballerina.lang_annotations.___init.$currentModuleInit(lang.annotations)
    at ballerina.lang_annotations.___init.ballerina_lang_annotations__init_(lang.annotations:65535)
    at 13473.upload_to_ftp.___init.$moduleInit(upload_to_ftp:65535)
    at 13473.upload_to_ftp.___init.$lambda$$moduleInit$(upload_to_ftp)
    at org.ballerinalang.jvm.scheduling.SchedulerItem.execute(Scheduler.java:486)
    at org.ballerinalang.jvm.scheduling.Scheduler.run(Scheduler.java:237)
    at org.ballerinalang.jvm.scheduling.Scheduler.runSafely(Scheduler.java:207)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)```
````

Comment: What's your ballerina version and ballerina integrator version?

Comment: Ballerina 1.0.4 and Ballerina Integrator 0.12.4 and VSCode Version: 1.40.1 (user setup)

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: Hi,No i didn't get any solution.

Comment: Did you check the below answer?

Comment: Yes. But didn't get proper and full output.

Comment: Still getting the above error or other error?

Comment: Other error. {"Message":"Error occurred uploading file to FTP.", "Resason":"org.wso2.ei.b7a.ftp.core.util.BallerinaFTPException"}

Comment: How to tell BI to load conf file through --b7a.config.file command

Comment: If your `ballerina.conf` file is in the project root level (same level with `Ballerina.toml` file), then no need to add this command

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203886/discussion-between-sumathi-and-pramodya-mendis).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mismatch of the version is problem here. Just install Ballerina Integrator alone which is packed with Ballerina 1.0.2 so no need to install Ballerina again or separately.

Locally installed "Ballerina Integrator with Ballerina" is lower version, In VSCode "Ballerina Integrator with Ballerina" is latest one. Mismatched version is the main problem which i was faced.

I have removed BI and Ballerina plugin from VSCode just tried the samples from random location which is used to refer locally installed BI with Ballerina,now its working fine

Answer (score 2):

To try out the Ballerina Integrator samples, please make sure that you have installed the `Ballerina Integrator` installer and using it to run your samples. You can download the latest Ballerina Integrator from [here](https://wso2.com/integration/ballerina-integrator/).

To check if you are executing Ballerina Integrator, execute `which ballerina` command and verify that it is similar to `<EI_HOME>/ballerina-integrator/bin/ballerina`.

Comment: I am Sure,i have installed Ballerina Integrator. Now how to run the Ballerina Integrator Samples & Where i have to put samples? Inside of `<EI_HOME>/ballerina-integrator/` or Any other folder? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can downgrade and upgrade Ballerina versions using the `ballerina dist` command.
`ballerina dist pull <distribution>` will fetch a given distribution and set it as the active version.

Comment: Apparently version is 1.0.4 and it does not have dist commands

Comment: I have uninstalled all ballerina from my laptop. From VSCode also uninstalled. After that installed from WSO2 EI 7.0.1 Installer, checked version from <EI_HOME>/ballerina-integrator/bin/ballerina it shows version as 1.0.2, Now let me know where i have put integration samples ?

Comment: After installing EI 7.0.1, install the VSCode extension for Ballerina Integrator as shown in https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WSO2.ballerina-integrator. You will find the integration samples in there.

Comment: @Fleur  After installing EI 7.0.1, installed VSCode Extension for Ballerina Integrator as you have mentioned in the comment, but it showing error alert notification," the dependent ballerina extension is not compatible please install latest " What should i do further